# Image enlarge on hover with screen edge detection using CSS3 transition

Tags: jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/1noeom3h/6/

When I hover over the image, it enlarges but half the information is missing. How do I get it so that the image being enlarged stays on the screen but follows the photo? So it's centered if it's got room, but if it doesn't have room, then it's offset?

```
<style type="text/css">
.zoom_img img{
    height:40px;
    width:50px;
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform 2.0s ease-in; 
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 2.0s ease-in; 
    -o-transition:-o-transform 2.0s ease-in;
    transition:transform 2.0s ease-in;
}

.zoom_img img:hover{
    -moz-transform:scale(2); 
    -webkit-transform:scale(2);
    -o-transform:scale(2);
    transform:scale(2);
}
</style>
```

Comment: will the images ever wrap to new lines? (say when the screen is too small)? or is this part of an interface that has a minimum width?

Comment: It shouldn't. I am using thumbnails and want 8 thumbnails in a row that I can hover over and expand to 500px x 400px. But I need them to stay within the parameters of the window which is where I'm having problems.. it expands but cuts off 3/4 of the image.

Comment: how are you adding the thumbnails to your `html`? are you looping through an array? or hard coding them? can you provide the code that generates the thumbs in your question please.

Comment: <div class="zoom_img"><img src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/yahoo-original.jpg" /> <img src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/yahoo-original.jpg" /> <img src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/yahoo-original.jpg" /> <img src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/yahoo-original.jpg" /></div>

Comment: i see your `html` in your jsfiddle.. how are you creating it.. are you using a language like `php` to output the data from a database?

Comment: Naw, I grabbed the code from another stackoverflow question and tried to make it work with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: your question the images are `50px`x`40px` with a scale or `2`.. but you want them to be a scale of `10`? have you looked at the answer below?

Comment: Yes, but it only works for the first image. I have 8 images per line. So when I try to hover over the second image to the right of the first image, the problem I had before resurfaces.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1noeom3h/12/ here is the updated jsfiddle that shows the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the first item in the list using the css pseudo class `:first-child` then you can use the `transform-origin` attribute to change the location from which the `scale` will happen.

You will need to be conscious of screens being scaled such that the images wrap to new lines, (effectively moving an item not first in the list to the left hand side of the screen)

**CSS**

```
.zoom_img img{
    height:40px;
    width:50px;
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform 2.0s ease-in; 
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 2.0s ease-in; 
    -o-transition:-o-transform 2.0s ease-in;
    transition:transform 2.0s ease-in;
}

.zoom_img img:hover{
    -moz-transform:scale(2); 
    -webkit-transform:scale(2);
    -o-transform:scale(2);
    transform:scale(2);
}

.zoom_img img:first-child{
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1noeom3h/7/)**

---

**EDIT**

It looks like you need to have better control over each of your `img` expand directions. here is some CSS that allows you to add a class to the images to make it expand down and to the right or down and to the left. (you can add as many or a few classes as you like each with their own `[transform-origin][2]` percentages but this should give you an idea to start

**CSS**

```
.zoom_img img{
    height:40px;
    width:50px;
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform 2.0s ease-in; 
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 2.0s ease-in; 
    -o-transition:-o-transform 2.0s ease-in;
    transition:transform 2.0s ease-in;
}

.zoom_img img:hover{
    -moz-transform:scale(2); 
    -webkit-transform:scale(2);
    -o-transform:scale(2);
    transform:scale(2);
}

.zoom_img img.goRight{
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
.zoom_img img.goLeft{
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="zoom_img">
    <img class="goRight" src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/yahoo-original.jpg" /> 
    <img class="goRight" src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/yahoo-original.jpg" /> 
    <img class="goRight" src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/yahoo-original.jpg" /> 
    <img class="goRight" src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/yahoo-original.jpg" />
    <img class="goLeft" src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/yahoo-original.jpg" /> 
    <img class="goLeft" src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/yahoo-original.jpg" /> 
    <img class="goLeft" src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/yahoo-original.jpg" /> 
    <img class="goLeft" src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/yahoo-original.jpg" />
</div>
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1noeom3h/11/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1noeom3h/15/

Any chance you know how I can take the hover function off and make it "onclick" only? I realize the hover is going to be a pain if I have multiple lines of photos.

Comment: it would not be easy with just `CSS` to emulate `onclick` (you have to fake the functionality by restyling `checkbox` `input`s) you would be much better to use javascript

Comment: I'm a bit of a newb at this; would you know how to make the java script? I could use :active in CSS but I don't think my users want to click and hold to view each image. Some people will want to save the photo so I'd need it to stay up for a bit.

Comment: i think at this point it appears you're attempting to re-invent the wheel when there are plenty of "out of the box" solutions that will do the things you are looking for. heres a list that you can have a play with: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/18/30-best-solutions-for-image-galleries-slideshows-lightboxes/